# CRM 2015 Plugin Registration Tool Error :Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to parse the OrganizationServiceFault

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I have installed the Plugin Pro-filer, when I attempt to debug the Plugin in CRM, which fires on a phone call create, it fails to debug, throwing the following exception "

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to parse the
>   OrganizationServiceFault

." the error is not very descriptive, I have been battling for hours trying to resolve this issue, I attempted reinstalling the SDK, but the issue still persists, I have used the registration tool on a Contact create successfully before, now I am out of idea, any ideas to the solution for this issue, the error message itself is not descriptive, here is the full error "

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to parse the
>   OrganizationServiceFault. Parameter name: serializedReport    at
>   PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.ExtractReport(String
>   serializedReport)    at
>   PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.DeserializeProfilerReport(String
>   assemblyFilePath, String logFilePath, Boolean isCrmDataStream)    at
>   PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerExecutionUtility.RetrieveReport(String
>   logFilePath, Boolean isCrmDataStream)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.CommonControls.Helper.ParseReportOrShowError(Window
>   window, FileBrowserView profilePathControl, Boolean
>   requireReportParse, ProfilerPluginReport& report) Inner Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Message does not contain a
>   serialized value.    at
>   PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.ExtractReportFromFault(OrganizationServiceFault
>   fault)    at
>   PluginProfiler.Library.ProfilerUtility.ExtractReport(String
>   serializedReport)

". Its unfortunate that CRM 2015 doesn't have the Developer Toolkit in the SDK so the registration tool seems to be the only way to register plugin successfully. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try looking in the server logs, if you are lucky you might get something more useful

Comment: Try using the ITracingService as well, at least you gwt an idea wjere in the code the plugin occurred. Even better, get the full stack trace logged by the tracing service.

Comment: I had a look at the log files, and the error appears as "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." I have a Database EDMX that I am reading data form an external SQL table, which uses EF 6, when I try and execute my plugin to profile it and debug, I get the above mentioned error, i tried to use EF version 5.0.0 and i still get the same issue, any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your plug-ins step ends with "(profiled)". You can get this error trying to use the default error logs, and people get a false positive thinking the profiler is installed because they highlight the plugin and it gives the option to uninstall rather than install. You need to select the plugins step to confirm your plugin is being profiled.